# why do I get [Errno 2]?

Tags: python, server

so I have created a server that as for now does a very simple task, it suppose to send to the browser a packet whitch contains the string "datatatata".
but it does'nt work, when running it and sending a request from browser, I keep getting [Errno 2]. the request is of course HTTP request
the code:

```
import socket


# functions

def get_file_data(filename):
    pass


def handle_client_request(file_path, client_socket):
    file_to_return = open(file_path, 'rb')
    file_content = file_to_return.read()
    client_socket.send(file_content)


def validate_client_request(client_request):
    # checks validation of request. for now validation is set to true
    validation = True
    # checks for requested URL
    desired_file_name = ""
    for i in client_request[5::]:
        if i != " ":
            desired_file_name += i
        else:
            break
    # checking file type
    file_type = ""
    if desired_file_name == "favicon":
        file_type = "ico"
    elif desired_file_name == "abstruct" or desired_file_name == "":
        file_type = "jpg"
    elif desired_file_name == "loading":
        file_type = "gif"

    if file_type == "":
        validation = False

    file_path = "C:\\Users\\hadad\\Desktop\\webroot\\imgs\\" + desired_file_name + "." + file_type
    return validation, file_path


def handle_client(client_socket):
    client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    valid_request, file_path = validate_client_request(client_request)
    if valid_request:
        handle_client_request(file_path, client_socket)
    else:
        client_socket.send("unvalid request. connection ended".encode())
    client_socket.close()


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
    server_socket.listen()

    # everlasting loop
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        handle_client(client_socket)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Networks/hed/good_server.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Networks/hed/good_server.py", line 60, in main
    handle_client(client_socket)
  File "C:/Networks/hed/good_server.py", line 46, in handle_client
    handle_client_request(file_path, client_socket)
  File "C:/Networks/hed/good_server.py", line 11, in handle_client_request
    file_to_return = open(file_path, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hadad\\Desktop\\webroot\\imgs\\abstruct.jpg'
```

Comment: As modern HTTP is a streaming protocol, using the default option is likely to hang your connection (and causing nothing to be returned, which typically browsers will abort and thus causing the error you saw).  Try setting up your socket with `socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)` (to follow the [`socketserver.TCPServer` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Lib/socketserver.py#L437-L449) which serves as the foundation of the built-in `http.server`), which should get you started on building your custom server.

Comment: yes I have fiixed it but now I get a new error when sending photos to browser

Comment: Well, read what the error message said and try too resolve it, as your new edit points to a very obvious issue.

Comment: but I do have such a directory. I wonder why it does'nt consider // as /. of course I don'nt have a file in C:\\Users\\hadad\\Desktop\\webroot\\imgs\\abstruct.jpg path, but I do have it in path C:\Users\hadad\Desktop\webroot\imgs\abstruct.jpg @metatoaster

Comment: do you have a very good reason for writing your own http server?  all security, performance, and so many other things will need to be addressed before you can put this live on the internet.  there are many embedded servers which will run within your application and can be controlled by your program.  python has a httpserver library which you can use for most purposes.

Comment: @KinjalDixit I currently learning socket programming and networks, it is for the sake of understanding. not an actual thing I would use

Comment: open a new interactive Python repl and verify that `open('C:\\Users\\hadad\\Desktop\\webroot\\imgs\\abstruct.jpg')` returns a file handle.

Comment: Also, it's generally bad form to completely change your question after it has been solved, though I didn't quite post that issue with requiring `SOCK_STREAM` as an answer... so I guess that's moot.

Comment: @metatoaster it shows me the same error

Comment: Clearly the file is not where you think it is.  Check for all spelling errors in the file name.

Comment: ok I think I may have found it @metatoaster checking if it works now....